# What does proxy_send_timeout really do in Nginx?

Tags: nginx

In Nginx documentation there are directives concering three differnet timeouts, that can be configured for "backend" servers as follows:

> `proxy_connect_timeout` Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server.
> It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds.

This is easy to understand -- Nginx is about to connect to an upstream "backend" server and if it can't connect within an X amount of time it will give up and return an error. The server is unreachable, has too many connections, etc.

> `proxy_read_timeout` Defines a timeout for reading a response from the
> proxied server. The timeout is set only between two successive read
> operations, not for the transmission of the whole response. If the
> proxied server does not transmit anything within this time, the
> connection is closed.

This also makes sense -- Nginx has already established a TCP connection with the "backend" server and is now about to actually send the request, but the server is taking long time to process and if it takes more than X amount of time, close the connection and return to the user.

I actually was surprised that Nginx closes the connection I thought it will keep the connection but return an error to the user. Sounds expensive to re-establish those "backend" TCP connections every time somethin times out.

> `proxy_send_timeout` Sets a timeout for transmitting a request to the
> proxied server. The timeout is set only between two successive write
> operations, not for the transmission of the whole request. If the
> proxied server does not receive anything within this time, the
> connection is closed.

This one I don't quite get. I do have a theory but I want someone to confirm it. The only value I can think of to this timeout is if the request payload is huge (e.g. big POST request with JSON, or document the user want to save).  Transmitting the request to the "backend" will require breaking the request into smaller MTU TCP segments and sending those as "chunks" of the original request. So technically we didn't actually send the request until we transmit all chunks to the server successfully. Is Nginx measuring the time between each chunk of the request? Is that what a "write" means in the doc? Once the request is actually sent, Nginx will start measuring the `proxy_read_timeout`?

Answer (score 7):

TCP/IP is a so-called "streaming" data transmission protocol. It is designed to let the party reading data over a TCP/IP connection not to have to necessarily care about sizes of "segments" or even packets. This translates to, in practice, a situation where a peer invoking some traditional "read" operation for obtaining data sent by the remote peer (e.g. [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) with Linux), won't necessarily read at once exactly as much data as what the remote end provided to a single "write" operation. The TCP/IP protocol implementation will invariably make IP packets of appropriate size from what was passed to a "write" operation at a time, and the implementation on the other end will assemble data back from those packets; but it won't *necessarily hand them to some "reading" client application with the same data boundaries!*

Example: A has 50Kb of data to send for every external system event, so much so they won't fit it in RAM all at the same time, so they send it in chunks of 16Kb which is the size of their sending buffer. So they first send 16Kb, then another 16Kb, then another 16Kb, and then finally 2Kb. The TCP/IP implementation might send these 50Kb, buffered in a 128Kb buffer internally (e.g. a kernel buffer), and only then send it over the network, which also has its own conditions. Some of these data, fragmented thus in a way the sending application isn't even aware of, arrive at the other end first -- due to network conditions -- and are assembled by the TCP/IP implementation there and put into a kernel buffer again. The kernel wakes up the process that wants to read the data -- reading all 30Kb of it. The receiver must decide if they expect more and how to make sense of how much more to expect -- the *format* of the "message" or data isn't something TCP/IP is concerned over.

This means Nginx can't know how much a client's request it will read at once for every `read` call it will do on a Linux-based system, for instance.

The documentation of `proxy_send_timeout` slightly hints at what's it for (emphasis mine), though:

> Sets a timeout for transmitting a request to the proxied server. The timeout is set only between two successive write operations, not for the transmission of the whole request. *If the proxied server does not receive anything within this time*, the connection is closed.

Thing is, since Nginx *proxies* a request -- meaning the request does not *originate* with it -- it waits for the "downstream" client (the remote end of the connection that sent the request to Nginx that the latter in its role as a "proxy" now expects to forward upstream) to transmit data of the request before it forwards (writes) it over the upstream connection.

The way I understand it if there is nothing received from downstream [during the timeout period of time] then the proxied server won't be receiving anything either -- and the connection is then closed.

Put another way, if said downstream does not send anything within the period of time indicated by `proxy_send_timeout`, Nginx will close the connection with the upstream.

For instance, consider a Web browser that sends a request to Nginx. The first piece is read by Nginx at time A. Assuming it will proxy the request to some upstream, it opens a connection to said upstream and transmits (writes) what it has received from the browser, over the upstream connection socket. It then simply waits for more pieces of the request data to be read from the browser -- if the next piece does not arrive after some timeout X relative to time A, it will close the connection to the upstream.

Pay mind that this does not necessarily mean it will close the connection to the Web browser -- it will certainly return some HTTP error status code for the request, but the Web browser connection lifetime is governed by a different set of conditions than `proxy_send_timeout` -- the latter only concerns Nginx's connections to the upstream.